# (Very) Large Simulink Input file

Tags: tcp, simulink, large-files

I have a very large simulink input file (*.csv) that is too big to the handled in a single node...

I am wondering if it is possible to not read the whole file once at the beginning of the simulation, but instead stream the data in real time as needed by the simulation.

My first thought was to implement a custom script in JAVA or C# (sender) that reads line by line the input csv file and **STREAM** the data to simulink via TCP . Simulink would receive the data using a TCP block receiver.

My questions are two:

1. Is my approach feasible?
2. Given the problem stated, what would
   be your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it would be easier to the run simulation using sequential chunks of the data, saving the model state at the end of each chunk, and starting the simulation from the state saved at the end of the previous chunk.  The doc describing how to do this is [Save and Restore Simulation State as SimState](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/saving-and-restoring-the-simulation-state-as-the-simstate.html).

Answer (score 1):

You might try writing an S-Function in C that opens your file and streams your data line by line. The easiest way to do this would be using the [S-Function Builder block](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sfunctionbuilder.html). You would nonetheless need to parse your file in C. (which, in the case of a CSV file, shouldn't be hard)